# Fixing bad sectors of a hard drive

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, hard-drive, badblocks

My hard drive is partly visible (only 4.1 GB of 2TB) in "Disks" and has a bad sector. I have tried using the smartmontools to check for bad sectors and then used `badblocks -svn /dev/sda` for which I get the response

```
badblocks: Permission denied while trying to determine device size
```

Then I tried to use installation utility but the 18.04 LTS stops responding at selecting language.

[image: error starting SMART self test]

[image: "Disk is OK, one bad sector"]

Edit 3: New development in the issue - the live usb has started to become unresponsive/ freezing.

Edit 4: using the method provided by 1st answer I am getting the error shown:

[image: Gparted: input/output error during read of /dev/sda]

[image: error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda]

[image: fdisk output - can't see the disk]

Comment: This doesn't look very good. I hope you have good backups. Go ahead and try doing my answer. Report back. I'm going to bed now, but send me a comment, and I'll return in the morning.

Comment: Hey @heynnema, I tried your method but it didn't work. I have added an image for it. Right now I have installed 20.04 LTS on another drive and tried to repeat the smart scan process, but the result was same and there is some error related to input/output of the disk.

Comment: You gave it an incorrect command. It's not /dev/sda. Please re-read my instructions and report back.

Comment: The commands given that you provided did not return a number for that hard drive. Please, is there any other way ? @heynnema

Comment: Show me the output of the `sudo fdisk -l` command. Do you have backups of the data on this drive... or do you, at this point, care about anything on this drive? If not, we'll lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive), then we'll install a fresh ext4 partition, then we'll bad block it.

Comment: Added both the screenshots. I don't care about the data as it was used in surveillance and I was installing OS on it for first time. Some error occurred saying the disk cannot be formatted and then suddenly disk started behaving like this. @heynnema

Comment: Right now it's night time in my time zone so I can respond after about 8 to 10 hours. Thank you in advance. @heynnema

Comment: It looks like you tried to install a fresh GPT partition table, yes? And it failed, yes? If both answers are "yes", try laying down a MBR partition table, and see what happens. It doesn't look good... the drive may be gone. Funny enough "fdisk" sees partition sdb1 and sdb2, which theoretically should be able to bad block... but maybe not. Did `fsck` run on sdb1 and sdb2? Report back later.

Comment: The sdb1 and sdb2 are from another drive where 20.04LTS is installed. So fdisk is not able to detect the drive. And there is an IDE Slave drive error in BIOS. Right now my computer is not even turning ON when I connect the drive with bad sector.@heynnema

Comment: Ah! Anyway, the drive is bad. Toss it. Replace it.

Comment: A thought just struck me... this is a SATA drive, correct? If not, are you sure the master/slave/cable select jumpers are correctly set?

Comment: Yes it's a SATA and not ATA. @heynnema

Comment: I saw your comment about IDE Slave drive error... and it made me think. Oh well, toss the drive.

Comment: Or see if there's any Seagate warranty left.

Comment: I hope it gets covered in warranty as manufacturing year is 2016. Thanks for your patience though. @heynnema

Comment: If my answer, and the comments, have been helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hi , How did you fix it finally? I have the same issue in my SSD and answer didnt help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Disks`, `fdisk`, and `gparted` screenshots don't look very promising...

**fsck**

First check your file system.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**bad block**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #1:**

The HDD is defective. Replace it. It may still be under warranty. Check with Seagate.

Comment: Why do you not badblocks an SSD? Anything dangerous or would it mean simply wasting write operations to do something SSDs already do by themselves?

Comment: @DonJoe The answer to that question is kind of involved. Google it.

Answer (score 2):

Conclusion: The Hard Drive is destroyed ( useless and cannot be repaired ). So if anyone one is facing similar problem, check if any solution mentioned in the comments work for you or ask a new question on the forum.

Comment: I added this info to my answer.