# Recurrent bad superblocks errors on my hard disk when trying to mount EXT4 filesystem on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fsck

I ran into a problem earlier this week where I booted my computer and one of my drives gave me an error about bad superblocks. I run Ubuntu 20.04 x64 on my laptop with EXT4. This error prevented me from mounting the drive. There are a lot of posts on AskUbuntu and other stackexchange sites about this error, and I tried all of the tools including `fsck`, `testdisk`, and others to no avail. So I finally ended up reformatting my drive. No worries, all the data was backed up so no loss.

Then today I did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and it suddenly triggered the superblock problem again. Like after the upgrade the computer screen went dark. And then I had to do a forced shutdown. When I booted again, the superblock error came back. Luckily this time the `fsck.ext4 -v /dev/xxx` worked for me. So my drive mounted successfully then.

So I am wondering what I should do to prevent this stuff from happening? Like is there some fragmentation on my hard drive, is my disk getting bad, or what else could it be? I want to figure out how to prevent this issue from happening again.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is the self-test info.

[image]

Comment: Replace the hard drive.

Comment: Open the **disks** app in your laptop. Go to the three dot menu and click on **Smart Data & Self Test**. Take a screenshot and add it to your question. If it says the drive is failing, buy a new drive.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the suggestion. I uploaded the image of the self-test as requested. Does this suggest getting a new drive.

Comment: 104 bad sector is the matter of concern. How old is the drive? If the disk is under warranty you should get it replaced. See [Fixing bad sectors of a hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278032/fixing-bad-sectors-of-a-hard-drive) for similar problems.

Comment: @user68186 Okay, that makes a lot more sense. The drive is probably about 3 years old or so. I am not sure if it is still under warranty, but I can check. Yes, I will look at fixing the bad sectors, and I will also look online for new drives :). Seems like it is not that expensive to get a new 1TB drive or the laptop--cheaper than it used to be.

Comment: You may want to get an 1 TB SSD instead of an HDD. It will be much faster.